# Flutter: Invalid `Podfile` file: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

Getting error **Invalid `Podfile` file: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)** when installing pod in flutter's iOS project.

Comment: Check your pod file it’s not in proper format.

Comment: I am getting this error with each project, which is created with flutter.

Comment: please share the detailed error message you are getting in terminal.

Comment: did you install the Pod not using Gem?